# $this->url() like thing in service locator in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a service locator in zf2 module defined as

```
class User implements  ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{

}
```

I want to use something similar to `$this->url() for views` here ..

is this possible.. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your Model implements the `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`, it is.

```
$sl  = $this->getServiceLocator();
$vhm = $sl->get('viewhelpermanager');
$url = $vhm->get('url');

$urlString = $url($name, $params, $options, $reuseMatchedParams);
```

See [`Zend\View\Helper\Url#__invoke()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/Url.php#L60-L73) for details of the params.

Comment: Let me say it like this: i know of none where it doesn't work ;)

Comment: Its [basePath()](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/BasePath.php). As you can see, there is [no baseUrl()](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend/View/Helper)

Comment: I am not able to get getServiceLocator in Service file.

Comment: For now (Zend 3), service name is `ViewHelperManager`, maybe service locator is case sensitive.